# appbar doesn't extend to top of page

Tags: html, css

I'm making as simple game as a webpage with HTML/CSS/JS (no framework). I decided to try out [muicss](https://www.muicss.com/) for styling. I added an appbar to the page, but there is still a white gap above it.

Here's an example:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>MUI CSS Appbar Example</title>
    <link
        href="https://cdn.muicss.com/mui-0.10.3/css/mui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css"
    />
    <script src="https://cdn.muicss.com/mui-0.10.3/js/mui.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="mui-appbar">
    <h1>Appbar</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I get

[image]

How do I get rid of the white stripe at the top? [Examples](https://www.muicss.com/examples/v1/css-js/appbar.html) [from their docs](https://www.muicss.com/examples/v1/css-js/appbar-helpers.html) don't have that. What am I missing

Answer (score 1):

Add custom CSS style...

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>MUI CSS Appbar Example</title>

  <style>
    h1 {
      margin-top: 0px!important;
    }
  </style>

  <link href="https://cdn.muicss.com/mui-0.10.3/css/mui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.muicss.com/mui-0.10.3/js/mui.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="mui-appbar">
    <h1>Appbar</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I think I probably don't need `!important`. Where can I read more about how this works? I'm surprised that the `margin` on the `h1` goes outside the parent `div`. Shouldn't the `div` grow to contain the `h1` and its margin?

Comment: Without the `!important` custom style can fail, that is there to override all previous styling. You can read more about CSS Box Model here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp and CSS !important Rule here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp

Comment: Yes, I understand what `!important` is. I also know it gets overused. Removing it here also requires moving the `<style>` tag to the last thing in the `<head>` for it to work. Thanks for the link about the box model. I'll read more about that to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

Immediately after posting this, I found that muicss declares a style

```
h1, h2, h3 {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

So the whitestripe is caused by the `margin-top` on the `h1` element.